# Inserting HTML into Word Using OpenXML

Tags: xhtml, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have some HTML stored in a database that I want to insert into a Word document using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.

Inspired by the article [here](http://yeshagupta.blogspot.com/2010/06/downloading-ms-word-2007-files-for-html.html), I tried the following code.

```
mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Xhtml,
    String.Format("<html><body>{0}</body></html>", html));
```

But this gives me the following error.

> '(My HTML Here)' ID is not a valid XSD ID

I really don't understand this error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Also, my biggest concern about this approach is that the HTML may not be perfectly formed and I suspect this code is not as forgiving as browsers are. Any recommendations for other possible approaches? I'm considering parsing the HTML and rendering it myself, but that will be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter is a part ID, not the part contents.

To set the part contents, you need to put well-formed XHTML into the `RootElement` property of the returned `AlternativeFormatImportPart`

Comment: Ah, so it is. Thanks. Anyone have any experience with this or know how forgiving the parser is?

Comment: I don't have any experience with it, but I assume that it's a strict parser.  You can use HTMLAgilityPack to well-form-ify the tag soup first.